# JavaScript Radio Buttons and Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

On selection of Yes on a radio button I'm trying to display a div, but I can't get the it to work. My code:

```
<input id="y" type="radio" name="experience" value="y"/>Yes
<input id="n" type="radio" name="experience" value="n"/>No

<style type="text/css">
.desc { display: none; }
</style>

<div id="yes" class="desc">
<p>You have Wielding Experience!</p>
</div>

<div id="no" class="desc">
<p>You have no Wielding Experience!</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){           
$("input[name='experience']").click(function(){
    if ($("input[name='experience']:checked").val() == 'y')
        $("#yes").show();      
    });
    });
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ditch the `@`, but also, where's the `name='location'` input in your HTML?

Comment: Ditched the @'s, oh that doesn't exist anymore, I'll edit it - same problem though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `radio` with `input`:

```
$("input[name='experience']").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name='experience']:checked").val() == 'y') {
        $("#yes").show();
    }
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKGVf/).

P.S.: replace all `<input ...>...</input>` with `<input ... />...`

Comment: That site looks great! But even with that code, mine still isn't working on Chrome/IE

Comment: My example works also in chrome and ie, can you show me your updated code?

Comment: I've edited my original post, it's basically the same as the code you posted

Comment: Replace your `script`-tag with: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Still nothing, maybe the issue is with my security settings? Are there any pre-requisites to using Javascript? (This is basically my first time using it)

Comment: This code should work. Because you are using jQuery, have you included jQuery in the `<head>`? `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>`

Comment: Oh, I see so I have that code in my head and thereafter I can just use <script> and </script>? It works now, thank you!

Comment: You can use `<script>` (and specially javascript) anytime, but `$` is an alias for `jQuery`, a javascript library. If you want to use this, you have to add this before.

Answer (score 2):

to select a radio button you must use input:radio and not just radio like that

$("input:radio[@name='experience']")

Answer (score 1):

I would write

if ($("input[name='experience']:checked").val() == 'y')

instead of

if ($("input[@name='location']:checked").val() == 'y')

ie input without the @ and using the actual name of the radio

But perhaps you mean

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
  $("input[name='experience']").click(function(e){
    if ($this).val() == 'y') {
        $("#yes").show();      
        $("#no").hide();      
    }
    else {
        $("#no").show();      
        $("#yes").hide();      
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#y').click(function(){
    $('#yes').show();
});
```